# Every derived table must have its own alias in C:\xampp\htdocs\company-directory\home.php

Tags: mysql, select

I am facing this error, please help.thanks in advance

```
SELECT companies.company_name
FROM (SELECT companies.company_name FROM companies
WHERE companies.profile_progress BETWEEN 80 AND 100)
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1248 Every derived table must have its own alias in C:\xampp\htdocs\company-directory\home.php:10 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\company-directory\home.php(10): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\company-directory\home.php on line 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code. I think it should work:

```
SELECT a.company_name FROM 
(SELECT companies.company_name 
FROM companies WHERE  companies.profile_progress 
BETWEEN 80 AND 100) a ORDER BY  RAND() LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thank you for the help , and its already done